# Tkinter: Why is my "<KeyRelease-Return>" Event not working?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get the value from an Entry Box when a 'Return Key Release' event occurs. But it does not seem to be working.

***My code is something like :***

```
EntryBox = Text(base, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", sendData(EntryBox.get(1.0, END)))
```

***My sendData function is:***

```
def sendData(param):
    if len(param) > 1:
            EntryBox.delete(1.0, END)
            insertText(param)
            s.sendall(str.encode(param))
            data = s.recv(4096)
            insertText(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

***My insertText function:***

```
def insertText(param):
        ChatLog.config(state = NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, param)
        ChatLog.config(state = DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind argument must be a function, not the result of a function. By adding `()` to the end of the function it's immediately executed and the result is provided to bind. You need to make a function and provide that:

```
EntryBox = Text(base, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
def on_return(event):
    sendData(EntryBox.get(1.0, END))
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", on_return)
```

For a function this tiny you could use `lambda` to create it if you want:

```
EntryBox = Text(base, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", lambda event: sendData(EntryBox.get(1.0, END)))
```

Comment: I would advise against using lambda except when absolutely necessary. In my experience, code is much easier to develop and maintain when your bindings call proper functions.

Comment: @Jonathan. It works now thank you. 
Also, while we are at it, Is there a way to print result in the text box in the END but to the right side? I tried searching online but couldn't find anything about it.
I'm looking for something like this: 
 --------------
| smth         |
|               v |
|                  |
|                  |
 --------------